# laravel 5.3 composer update error related with ide-helper

Tags: laravel

> post-update-cmd: Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
>   post-update-cmd: php artisan ide-helper:generate
>   Executing command (CWD): php artisan ide-helper:generate
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Connection::resolverFor()

Script php artisan ide-helper:generate handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Comment: Not sure what the question is nor what solutions you have tried.

Comment: "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "php artisan ide-helper:meta",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
even i comment out the "php artisan ide-helper:generate" still the error persist.
i have tried before removing the package ide-helper and reinstall it after. it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this command in cmd for faster composer install or update

```
// unix
php -m | grep xdebug
// windows
php -m | findstr xdebug

composer install --prefer-dist -vvv --profile

composer update --prefer-dist -vvv --profile
```